# Codeigniter upgrade 1.7 to 2 Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, upgrade

I want to migrate my application from CI 1.7.2 to 2x.
The folder structure for 2x and for 1.7x are entirely different.
What is my need is upgrade my app without any changes...?

Thank u guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will need to be changes made to your code.

Please follow the guide at: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html